# How can I get gradient's endColor to be same as MaterialCardView's background color with "elevation overlay" (in night mode)?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-drawable

I'm trying to do a card component ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvfVx.png)) for my Android Kotlin app. I've set gradient to be on top of image for title readability, and I want its color to blend with card's background.

In the day mode cards background is no different from `?attr/colorSurface`, so I've set it as gradient endColor. But, in night mode there is an "elevation overlay" thing that changes cards bg color to slightly lighter one by applying colorOnPrimary with some alha on top (based on elevation). So, this thing is changing cards bg color, but not my gradient's endColor — gradient stays black while card bg is dark [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrEfM.png). **How can I get gradient's endColor to be same as cards bg with "elevation overlay"?** Thanks in advance!

layout/activity_main_article.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            tools:srcCompat="@sample/articles_images" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/activity_main_article_gradient"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="@sample/articles_headings" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_article_preview"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_remove_red_eye_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_article_edit"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_edit_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_article_share"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_share_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

drawable/activity_main_article_gradient.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="?attr/colorSurface"/>
</shape>
```

[Full project](https://gitlab.com/delight_aug/blogger/-/tree/458ce2385663aa03b6b3c5f8e7427efbd9f06668) on GitLab, link to the relevant commit.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks for the comment! Now, what I understand is that the thing is called "elevation overlay" and is calculated from colorOnSurface and some alpha and  painted on top of colorSurface. But how can I apply it to a gradient? Also, I didn't understood what you were trying to say about cardView.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Can you post your theme? Do you define colorSurface?

Comment: No worries! I uploaded my [project](https://gitlab.com/delight_aug/blogger) to gitlab, so you can see whatever you need. I didn't set custom colorSurface, only primary/secondary sets of colors.